# Why are there differences in using merge and %in%?

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have two datasets that I'd like to merge via two identifying variables (up and ver_u):

```
  df1 looks like this:
  up          ver_u
  257001          1
  1010            1
  101010          1
  100316          1

 df2 looks like this:
 up             ver_u      code_uc       quantity
500116          1         395884             1
100116          1         36761              2
160116          1         81308              3
100116          1         76146              1
113216          1         6338               1
101116          1         33887              1
```

What I would like to do is to take out a subset of df2 where their up and ver_u matches with those in df1. I did this in two different ways and I got different answers.

First method:

```
pur <- merge(df2, df1,by=c("up","ver_u"))
```

Second method:

```
test <- df2[(df2$up %in% df1$up) & (df2$ver_u %in% df1$ver_u),]
```

They are giving me different number of observations and I don't see why they are giving me a difference.

When I used merge on dataframe test with the following code, I got the same number of observations, but the two resulting dataframes I got are still different.

```
pur1 = merge(test, df1,by=c("up","ver_u"))
```

Is there some systematic differences of using merge and %in%?

Would greatly appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `merge` is comparing row by row for both columns, while `%in%` is comparing one row by all other rows. Example:

```
#dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                  y = c(2,3,4))
df1
#   x y
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 4

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(2,3,1,3),
                  y = c(3,1,4,1))
df2
#   x y
# 1 2 3
# 2 3 1
# 3 1 4
# 4 3 1

# using merge
merge(df1, df2, by = c("x", "y"))
#   x y
# 1 2 3

# using %in%
df1[(df1$x %in% df2$x) & (df1$y %in% df2$y), ]
#   x y
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 4
```